# Rails - Namespace params ID not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up posts in a folder called 'contents' and then it fell over when I tried to delete the records. Why am I getting this error?

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"content/stories", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

> Routes.rb

```
 namespace :content do
    resources :posts
  end
```

> PostsController

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end

def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
  @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to content_posts_path
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: @post.errors.full_messages.first
  end
end

def show
end

def delete
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
  post = Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to :back
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content)
  end
end
```

> show.html

```
<ol>
  <% for p in @posts %>
    <li>
      <%= p.title %>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_content_post_path(@post) %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', content_post_path(@post), method: :delete %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Comment: `edit_content_post_path(@post)` here you are passing `@post` try like this `edit_content_post_path(@posts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@post` is not defined, you probably need to use `p` in place of `@post`.

Also in your `show.html` which corresponds to `show` action, not sure how you are getting `@posts`.